# How to compare plain array with array of object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, intersect

I wanted the result like "11" only , i wanted to compare array of object with plain array
whenever am trying to use filter it's show blank result. wanted to avoid map or loops. if that possible with filters only.

```
 const rows2 = [{
    userId: "a8c26932-2393-4aac-ba03-1314860110c9",
  },
  {
    userId: "4a6fe3d6-8ff1-4488-b7bd-15b033ffa4d1",
  }
]

const arr2 = ["4a6fe3d6-8ff1-4488-b7bd-15b033ffa4d1", "a8c26932-2393-4aac-ba03-1314860110c9", "11"];
```

// expected result : 11

Comment: You can do something like this: `arr2.filter((v) => !rows2.some(({ userId }) => userId === v));`

Comment: Can you modify row2 structure?

Comment: get the row2 userIds in to a set and then use filter on arr2 and check if set has

Comment: sorry structure comes from other dependency , but Thank you @cmgchess You solved it :)